# Are there bounds on the Spearman correlation of a sum of two variables?

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, bounds

Given $n$-vectors $x, y_1, y_2$ such that the Spearman correlation coefficient of $x$ and $y_i$ is $\rho_i = \rho(x,y_i)$, are there known bounds on the Spearman coefficient of $x$ with $y_1 + y_2$, in terms of the $\rho_i$ (and $n$, presumably)? That is, can one find (non-trivial) functions $l(\rho_1,\rho_2,n), u(\rho_1,\rho_2,n)$ such that 
$$l(\rho_1,\rho_2,n) \le \rho(x,y_1+y_2) \le u(\rho_1,\rho_2,n)$$

**edit**: per @whuber's example in the comment, it appears that in the general case, only the trivial bounds $l = -1, u = 1$ can be made. Thus, I would like to further impose the constraint:

- $y_1, y_2$ are permutations of the integers $1 \ldots n$.

Comment: Only knowing $\rho_{1}, \rho_{2}$, the interval containing $\rho(x, y_{1} + y_{2})$ must include $\rho_{1}$ and $\rho_{2}$: for each $y_{1}, y_{2}$ could have very small values (while having any rank-order), and thus simply "jitter" the values in $y_{1}$ when added to $y_{1}$. Thus the rank-order of $y_{1}$ wouldn't be affected. I don't know if the interval can exceed the $\rho_{i}$.

Comment: @caracal Good observations.  The interval definitely can be wider than the $\rho_i$: just consider the case where both correlations are zero.  The correlation with the sum can easily be nonzero--it can range all the way from -1 to 1.  E.g., x = (1,2,3,4,5); y1 = (3,-10,2,10,1); y2 = (-8,9,-2,-9,4); y1+y2 = (-5,-1,0,1,5) has $\rho_1=\rho_2=0$ but $\rho=1$.

Comment: @whuber: this seems to imply only trivial bounds exist (i.e. $l = -1, u = 1$). Perhaps I have to throw another constraint at the problem.

Comment: @shabbychef No, you have posted a nice problem: it's not trivial.  In case $\rho_1 = \rho_2 = 1$, for instance, the *only* possibility is $\rho = 1$.  I suspect the bounds are nontrivial except when $\rho_1 = \rho_2 = 0$; they must get narrower as $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ approach $\pm 1$.

Comment: @whuber Neat idea. Geometrically, I think I understand your principle in terms of moving points into the desired quadrants of the centered scatter-plot. However, I think there's another issue: Spearman's $\rho$ only assumes ordinality, thus sums or differences like $y_{1} + y_{2}$ are not a-priori meaningful.

Comment: @Caracal There's nothing faulty about @shabbychef's formulation.  Spearman's rho can be computed for so-called "continuous" data just fine.  You have actually put your finger on the entire difficulty, which is characterizing the interaction between addition and ranking.  One potential application is this: suppose $y_1$ is a response variable and $-y_2$ is a vector of unknown errors.  What can we say about the Spearman correlation between $x$ and the *true* values $y_1 - y_2$ given a measured correlation with $y_1$ and an assumed correlation with $-y_2$?

Comment: Here’s another pathological case.  Suppose that $x = y_1$ and $y_1 = -y_2$. Then $\rho(x, y_1 + y_2) = 0$, but $\rho_1 = 1$ and $\rho_2 = −1$.  

It might be enlightening to think about a  simpler,  probabilistic version of the problem.
Let $X$, $Y_1$, and $Y_2$ be random variables, each with marginally Uniform distributions.  Now let $G$ be the CDF of $Y_1 + Y_2$.  What can we say about $Cov(X, G(Y_1 + Y_2))$ based on $Cov(X,Y_1)$ and $Cov(X,Y_2)$?

Comment: One more note.  Since $G$ is a non-decreasing function, it feels like there might be a subadditive relationship between $Cov(X, G(Y_1 + Y_2))$ and $Cov(X,Y_1)$ and $Cov(X, Y_2)$.  The relationship would have to take into account the signs of the the latter two covariances.

Comment: @vqv: this is a good point. One of the copula inequalities might be relevant here.

Answer (score 4):

Spearman's rank correlation is just the Pearson product-moment correlation between the ranks of the variables. Shabbychef's extra constraint means that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the same as their ranks and that there are no ties, so they have equal standard deviation $\sigma_y$ (say). If we also replace x by its ranks, the problem becomes the equivalent problem for the Pearson product-moment correlation.
By definition of the Pearson product-moment correlation,
$$\begin{align}
\rho(x,y_1+y_2) 
  &= \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(x,y_1+y_2)}
          {\sigma_x \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(y_1+y_2)}} \\
  &= \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(x,y_1) + \operatorname{Cov}(x,y_2)}
          {\sigma_x \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(y_1)+\operatorname{Var}(y_2)
                          + 2\operatorname{Cov}(y_1,y_2)}} \\
  &= \frac{\rho_1\sigma_x\sigma_y + \rho_2\sigma_x\sigma_y}
          {\sigma_x \sqrt{2\sigma_y^2 + 2\sigma_y^2\rho(y_1,y_2)}} \\
  &= \frac{\rho_1 + \rho_2}
          {\sqrt{2}\left(1+\rho(y_1,y_2)\right)^{1/2}}. \\
\end{align}$$
For any set of three variables, if we know two of their three correlations we can put bounds on the third correlation (see e.g. [Vos 2009](http://www.informaworld.com/smpp/content~content=a906010843), or from [the formula for partial correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Using_recursive_formula)):
$$\rho_1\rho_2 - \sqrt{1-\rho_1^2}\sqrt{1-\rho_2^2} \leq \rho(y_1,y_2) \leq 
  \rho_1\rho_2 + \sqrt{1-\rho_1^2}\sqrt{1-\rho_2^2} $$
Therefore
$$\frac{\rho_1 + \rho_2}
       {\sqrt{2}\left(1+\rho_1\rho_2 + \sqrt{1-\rho_1^2}\sqrt{1-\rho_2^2}\right)^{1/2}}
  \leq \rho(x,y_1+y_2) \leq
 \frac{\rho_1 + \rho_2}
       {\sqrt{2}\left(1+\rho_1\rho_2 - \sqrt{1-\rho_1^2}\sqrt{1-\rho_2^2}\right)^{1/2}}
$$
if  $\rho_1 + \rho_2 \geq 0$; if $\rho_1 + \rho_2 \le 0$ you need to switch the bounds around.

Comment: But the real problem is that ranks don't add.  See my comment to the question.

Comment: @vqv but if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are permutations of the integers $1\ldots n$ then they are exactly the same as their ranks.

Comment: half the sum of permutations need not be a permutation; But this is very close, and answers the question for Pearson, I believe.

Comment: The ranked values of $y_1 + y_2$ are in general a nonlinear function of $y_1 + y_2$ — even if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are each a permutation of the integers $1,\ldots,n$.  Here’s an example: $y_1 = (1,2,3,4)$ and $y_2 = (2,3,1,4)$. Then $y_1+y_2 = (3,5,4,8)$ and $rank(y_1+y_2) = (1,3,2,4)$.  Plot $y_1+y_2$ against $rank(y_1+y_2)$ and you’ll see that there is no linear relationship between the two.  The above assertion that $\rho(x,y_1+y_2) = Cov(x,y_1+y_2) / \cdots$ **is in general false**, even under the assumption that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are permutations of the integers.

Comment: @vqv You're quite right. I was too hasty to attempt an answer before leaving for the christmas break. I hadn't come across that inequality relating the Pearson correlation of three variables before. Here's another ref for it complete with 3D visualisations: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2684832 . I still think it might have *some* relevance, so I won't delete my answer, though I can't see how to fix it either.